# gradle war: how to force inclusion of transitively provided dep?

Tags: gradle

Having this `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public" }
}

configurations {
    providedCompile {
        exclude module: 'commons-httpclient' // here it doesn't work
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'

    providedCompile ('org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:2.3.3.Final') {
        //exclude module: 'commons-httpclient' // here it works
    }
}
```

I expect to have this war:

```
WEB-INF/
WEB-INF/lib/
WEB-INF/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
```

but only have this:

```
WEB-INF/
```

If I un-comment 2nd `exclude` and comment 1st `exclude`, it works as needed.

If this is expected behavior, how can I otherwise globally exclude a particular transitive from provided libs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that this is the "right" thing to happen, as `compile` actually extends from `providedCompile`:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

configurations.compile.extendsFrom.each {
    println "$it"
}
```

So, my solution was the following:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public" }
}

configurations {
    forceInclude {}
}

dependencies {
    providedCompile 'org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:2.3.3.Final'

    forceInclude 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'
}

war {
    classpath += configurations.forceInclude
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wants the kotlin version, here it is :

```
val forceInclude: Configuration by configurations.creating

dependencies {
    forceInclude("commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1")
}

tasks.war {
    classpath(forceInclude)
}
```